# Canonical sheaf of product of two smooth projective curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C_1, C_2$ be two smooth projective curves of genus atleast $2$. Let $X:=C_1 \times C_2$. If $P_1, P_2$ are denoted as the first and second projections, then it is known that the canonical bundle relation is given as follows : $K_X := P_1^*(K_{C_1}) \otimes P_2^*(K_{C_2})$.

From this relation is it elementary to see that $h^1(K_X)=h^1(\mathcal O_X) >0$?

Any hint or explaination is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the Kunneth formula (ref [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BEC) or [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34673/kunneth-formula-for-sheaf-cohomology-of-varieties)), yes! The Kunneth formula says that for quasi-compact schemes $X$ and $Y$ over a field $k$ with affine diagonal (separated implies affine diagonal, for instance) and for $\mathcal{F}$ a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, $\mathcal{G}$ a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module, we have a canonical isomorphism $$H^n(X\times_{\operatorname{Spec} k} Y, p_1^*\mathcal{F}\otimes_{X\times_{\operatorname{Spec} k} Y} p_2^*\mathcal{G}) \cong \bigoplus_{p+q=n} H^p(X,\mathcal{F})\otimes_k H^q(Y,\mathcal{G}).$$

This gives us that $H^1(X,K_X) \cong H^1(C_1,K_{C_1}) \otimes_k H^0(C_2,K_{C_2}) \oplus H^0(C_1,K_{C_1}) \otimes_k H^1(C_2,K_{C_2})$ in our case. As $H^1(C_i,K_{C_i})\cong k$ by Serre duality and $h^0(C_i,K_{C_i}) = g$ by Riemann-Roch, we have that $h^1(K_X)>0$. Noting that $h^1(K_X)=h^1(\mathcal{O}_X)$ and this is calculated by the same expression by Serre duality, we're done.

Comment: $h^0(C_{i}, K_{C_{i}}) =g$ is by the definition of geometric genus, right?

Comment: Sure, that's another way to see that.

Comment: @KReiser Do we need the projective assumption ? In my proof which uses $\dim X\times Y=\dim X+\dim Y$, the fact that $X\times Y$ is smooth, the fact that $\Omega_{X\times Y}\cong p_1^*\Omega_{X}\oplus p_2^*\Omega_{Y}$ and exercise II.5.16.d) from Hartshorne I don't find where the assumption is used and I believe that everything is well defined without it.

Comment: @raisinsec non-projective (irreducible) curves are affine, so there's no need to calculate higher cohomology in that case.

Comment: @KReiser I was more talking about the isomorphism $\omega_{X\times Y}\cong p^*_1\omega_X\otimes p_2^*\omega_Y$. For the inequality I agree with you. Maybe it's off topic, you tell me, but it's one of the first posts I get when asking google why we need projectivity of $X,Y$ for the isomorphism.

Comment: @raisinsec See Hartshorne exercise II.8.3. One set of assumptions that gives you $\omega_{X\times Y} \cong p_1*\omega_X\otimes p_2^*\omega_Y$ is $X,Y$ smooth over a field; no need for anything beyond that.